# Ionic plugin for Image Viewer

Tags: image, ionic-framework, npm, plugins, angular5

I want to use a ionic plugin to show image with zoom functionality and rotate buttons. Do anyone know any good plugin or if not how to implement rotate button with ionic native photo viewer

Answer (score 0):

I found [PhotoEditor](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/), but you must pay

Answer (score 0):

I have used plugin "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0", for image viewing and zooming.

Please find below code.

```
    <img src={{blog.profilepicture}} imageViewer class="profilePicture" onError="this.src='assets/sliderimg/defaultuser.png'">
```

This plugin does not provide rotation. you need to add extra functionality.